# HybridAuth Social Login returns from social network to Page Not Found

Tags: authentication-authorization

I installed HybridAuth Social Login module on Drupal 7, and tested it with Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and LinkedIn. Clicking any of these four icons in the Log in form of my site functions to the extent that a new page opens, which shows my username, profile photo and/or other basic information from the social network in question, and asks me to give permission for my Drupal website to access my social network account information.

When I click Agree, I return to a half-filled registration form at my Drupal website. Typically the email address is missing. When I complete the form and click Create account, my browser says Page Not Found, and this kind of a link is shown in address bar:

http://my.website.com/hybridauth/window/[SocialNetwork]?destination=node&destination_error=node

... where [SocialNetwork] is Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, or Google.

Looks like I am nearly ready with the setup, but something is yet misconfigured.

When installing the module, I have followed the instructions on this page, to the extent that I understood it:

https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth

Take the first instructed step:

"Download HybridAuth library (link), and unpack it into 'sites/all/libraries/hybridauth' folder"

As I open the offered zip package, I find a root folder which contains README.md and other stuff, and subfolders additional-providers and hybridauth. I choose to copy the contents of the zip subfolder hybridauth into server folder '/var/www/html/sites/all/libraries/hybridauth'. A vague interpretation of vague instructions. Then I installed Chaos Tool Suite and the HybridAuth module.

Then I connected the module with my Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and LinkedIn developer accounts. And then happened what I describe at start of this post.